# Regular expression. Find strings that ends with these 2 particular special characters

Tags: php, regex

{( Hi whats up? this is a first bracket: (... )}

Now, I want to fetch the text that is between the {( and )} characters.

I did this:

```
preg_match('/\{\(([^\)\}]+)\)\}/',$string,$match);
```

But it doesn't work. However, if I remove the **(** which is inside the text, it works. But I will need the **(** inside the texts.

How do I filter the texts between the {( and )} characters.?

Comment: Your regex does work for the input you've provided. [Check it out](http://regex101.com/r/nR0nG9) with lively colors !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.*?` instead of `[^\)\}]+`

As a side-note, you could have used `[^)}]+` because `)` and `}` have no special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: Maybe add the lazy flag, instead of making the match lazy... `preg_match("/\\{\\((.*)\\)\\}/uU", $searchText)`

Comment: it didnt work at all. Nothing changed, the whole string remained as it is, like there was no preg_match function called.

Comment: @user3382146 Hmm... does your actual text span across multiple lines? If so, try adding the `s` modifier to make the `.` match newlines.

Comment: @PhillSparks Meh I hate that flag. It makes your regex soooo unreadable when it gets complexer.

Comment: What do you mean "the whole string remained as it is"? The string should not change, `$match` should be filled up.

Comment: I will tick this answer as soon Stackoverflow allows me to. 4 minutes remaining, they say.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex works exactly as it should:

```
$string = '{( Hi whats up? this is a first bracket: (... )}';
preg_match('/\{\(([^\)\}]+)\)\}/',$string,$match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

This produces the output ([see demo](http://regex101.com/r/fM6vJ6)):

```
string(44) " Hi whats up? this is a first bracket: (... "
```

Which is exactly what's between the strings `{(` and `)}`.

**Notes:**

- You don't need to escape `)` or `}` inside character classes. When inside a character class, they behave like normal characters and lose their meta-character properties. So instead of `[^\)\}]`, you could just use `[^)}]`.
- If you want to simplify the regex, you can use `/\{\((.*?)\)\}/` instead. This captures anything `(.*?)` between the strings. `.*` matches everything except newlines and the `?` makes it non-greedy, so it matches as minimum as possible.
- If your string spans multiple lines, then the current regex wouldn't work. You *can* use the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to solve this. The `s` modifier changes the default behavior of the dot meta-character. With the `s` modifier set, a `.` will match newlines too.